# Advices on wrapping a handler with a loop

Tags: android, timer, handler

I have been trying lately to add a timer into my app. I used a handler and the public run method to do that. So far, I have only managed to get the timer to run for one second. I tried to use a while loop but no matter where I put it the app crashed as soon as I started the timer. I would be happy if someone could give me an example of using a loop in this situation so that the timer will run  as long as I want it to.

Here is my code:

```
if (v == btnStart) {
            Toast.makeText(ScoreBoardActivity.this, "The game has started. ENJOY!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btnStart.setText("STOP GAME");
            int playTime = (getIntent().getExtras().getInt("gameTime")) / 10;
            Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        int playTime = (getIntent().getExtras().getInt("gameTime")) / 10;
                        if (sec1 < 9) {
                            sec1 = sec1 + 1;
                            tvSec1.setText(String.valueOf(sec1));
                            tvSec10.setText(String.valueOf(sec10));
                            tvMin10.setText(String.valueOf(min10));
                            tvMin1.setText(String.valueOf(min1));
                        } else if (sec1 == 9 && sec10 < 5) {
                            sec1 = 0;
                            sec10 = sec10 + 1;
                            tvSec1.setText(String.valueOf(sec1));
                            tvSec10.setText(String.valueOf(sec10));
                            tvMin10.setText(String.valueOf(min10));
                            tvMin1.setText(String.valueOf(min1));
                        } else if (sec1 == 9 && sec10 == 5 && min1 < 9) {
                            sec1 = 0;
                            sec10 = 0;
                            min1 = min1 + 1;
                            tvSec1.setText(String.valueOf(sec1));
                            tvSec10.setText(String.valueOf(sec10));
                            tvMin10.setText(String.valueOf(min10));
                            tvMin1.setText(String.valueOf(min1));
                        } else if (sec1 == 9 && sec10 == 5 && min1 == 9 && min10 < playTime) {
                            sec1 = 0;
                            sec10 = 0;
                            min1 = 0;
                            min10 = min10 + 1;
                            tvSec1.setText(String.valueOf(sec1));
                            tvSec10.setText(String.valueOf(sec10));
                            tvMin10.setText(String.valueOf(min10));
                            tvMin1.setText(String.valueOf(min1));
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
```

Comment: Show the error. Are you sure you are getting arguments with your intent? What is sec1, sec10, min1, min10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `PostDelayed(handler, 1000)` in each Run() call to schedule another run after 1 second:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ...
        handler.PostDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}
handler.PostDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
```

You can't use while loops and sleeps inside handler as that would block a UI thread making your app unresponsive and eventually crash.

Comment: and if it has to be accurate it is the better to use `postAtTime` or `postDelayed` with a "adjusted more or less 1000ms"

Comment: Can you show the way to do it with the code I've written? Because for some reason it's not working for me.

Comment: Replace the `...` with the code from your run() method. make sure handler is final (see my edit). And if something is still not working for you, post errors. If people have to guess what's wrong, you will likely not get any answers.

Comment: All right, it's working. Thanks a lot man! One more thing though, how can I add a stoping condition to this?